# gitscc installing offline

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I'm using [GitSCC](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) with VS 2100 and it works really nice. Although I prefer offline installations that didn't bother me until now. Now I have to install it on the computer which cannot have a network connection (*I mean it can have, but it doesn't*) so I need the part which is installed from within VS 2010 (GitScc plugin) in the form of offline installer.

Anyone knows where it can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google it! [First link that I found](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) Visual Studio 2010 version is only available with extension manager.

Visual Studio 2008 is still available as an offline install.

Comment: Yes. If you notice that is the same link I linked to in my question. I thought so too about the 2010 version; it's a shame. Oh well, thanks for settling this matter up.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download the VSIX](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c/file/29105/31/GitSccProvider.vsix) from the gallery site, then double-click the file to install it.